# Find a number in the sum of power of two

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server

We have the following items for the user to choose from:

1. item 1
2. item 2
3. item 3
4. item 4

When user selects the item(s) and submits, then we save the information like

- if item1 and item2 (2^1, 2^2) are selected, then 2+4=6
- if item1 and item3 (2^1, 2^3), then 2+8=10
- suppose, if user select all the items, then 30.

**I want to check whether user selected the item1 or item2 or item3 or item4 from the already selected values.
How to find this in c# or ms-sql or in javascript?**

Comment: Consider the number in it's binary form. Each digit that is set to 1 is a selected item. Each digit that is set to 0 is an unselected item.

Comment: So basically, you know only the final sum, and you want to figure out which items were selected by the user. Say if `sum= 12` then your result will be that item2 and item3 were selected. Am I right??

Comment: Correction: You say `if user select all the items, then 30` but this should be `if user select all the items, then 15` - because your lowest order item should be represented by 2^0, not 2^1

Answer (score 1):

Basically, representing a number as a sum of powers of two is what the binary number representation is all about. Consider 19 = 1 + 2 + 16, so the binary is 10011. If you want to check whether the sum contains a particular power of two, you can use the [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

`if(myNum & (1 << i))` will check whether the ith bit is set, or, in other words, if the sum contains 2 to the power of i.

Comment: For JavaScript bitwise operators reference, see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand in checking the bit. if user selected the item1 and item2, then result is 6. For 6 binary is 0110, for 2 binary is 10. How do I check, whether 2 is exists in 6.

Comment: You check the second bit. Just do 0110 & 0010 and check if this is zero. This is essentially what if(myNum & (1 << i)) is doing.

Comment: You take 00....001 (which is 1), then shift it 2 bits to the left and get  00....00100 (which is 1 << i), then & it with your number

Comment: sorry I can't understand this calculation. Can you please give any reference?

Comment: @JeevaJsb: I already have. Check out the link for bitwise operations in my answer

Comment: Sorrry Armen. From you answer what is myNum and i. Do you represent myNumb as 19? Do we need to loop 10011 and i representing ith bit? If so, From which side we need to loop? from Left or RIght?

Comment: @JeevaJsb: myNum is 19, it's your sum. i is the index (0-based) of the bit you want to check( counted from the right of the number). If you want to find all the 1 bits, then iterate as such: `for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)`

Answer (score -1):

In C#, use an enum field with flags like this:

```
[Flags] // This Attribute ensures that these items are handled as flags
public enum itemFlags
{
    None = 0
    item1 = 1,
    item2 = 2,
    item3 = 4,
    item4 = 8
}
```

It is important that all values are powers of 2, and that you have None = 0 (if no flag is set). Then you can use the ToString-Method to get all flags that are set.

For example,

```
Console.WriteLine(((itemFlags)9).ToString())
```

should output "item1, item4".

**Edit:**

To find out whether a flag is selected, you can also use the HasFlags-Method:

```
itemFlags myFlags = itemFlags.item1 | itemFlags.item3;
bool isItem1Selected = myFlags.HasFlag(itemFlags.item1);
Console.WriteLine(isItem1Selected.ToString());
```

This should print "True".

Comment: The OP wants to combine the values, so you should provide sample code that demonstrates how to combine them (using `|`)

Comment: I understood it that way that the OP wanted to find out from an already selected combination (like "10") which flags are set?

Comment: OP has clarified the question now, so this answer looks good.